# How to use openAM with openDS for data authentication

Tags: ldap, opends, openam

How openDS and openAM can be configured together to authenticate data.... ?

Is this possible that openDS is installed on some other machine on network and openAM is using it and if yes then how?

What is the use of LDAP here?

What is the use web agent and policy agents?

Please help me to find answers of these questions....

Answer (score 4):

These questions are the basis of OpenAM and I recommend that you read some introduction materials about OpenAM. A good reference is the OpenAM book published by PacktPub : https://www.packtpub.com/openam/book.

OpenAM is embedding OpenDS as its configuration datastore, and can leverage OpenDS (or ForgeRock led OpenDJ, the continued open source LDAP directory project derived from OpenDS) as the user data store. In both cases, OpenAM interacts with OpenDS using LDAP, as OpenDS is an LDAP directory server.

OpenAM Installation guide describes installation of OpenAM with OpenDS/OpenDJ as the User datastore installed on a different machine: http://openam.forgerock.org/doc/install-guide/OpenAM-Install-Guide.html

Web agents and policy agents are software agents that are installed on Web applications to communicate with the OpenAM service and provide Authentication and Authorization.

Kind regards,

Ludovic.